# Cannot run python script in command line - urllib3.util.ssl_

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

When I run a python script in Pycharm it works perfectly.  When I try to run it via the command line it errors:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scripts\KD.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scripts\Kariba_Dwell.py", line 10, in <module>
    import s3fs
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3fs\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import S3FileSystem, S3File
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3fs\core.py", line 15, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 30, in <module>
    import botocore.credentials
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\credentials.py", line 42, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import InstanceMetadataFetcher, parse_key_val_file
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 7, in <module>
    from urllib3.util.ssl_ import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py)
```

Comment: what version of python is this, is it `3.5.x`?

Comment: I am using version 3.7.6

Comment: Same problem, did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate your environment in the command-line.

For instance: Assume your environment name is `conda_torch`

`conda activate conda_torch` then an activated environment will be available.

Then you should type: `python KD.py`

[image]